Enhancing yogurt with collagen peptides
If I add collagen peptides powder to the mix of milk and yogurt before ripening, will the end product retain collagen peptides or the bacteria will reprocess the molecules?

It doesn't look like there have been any studies on collagenase activity in yogurt. I would expect some quite significant texture changes as the collagen hydrates and coagulates with the acid conditions in yogurt.
